# Eliminate a X element on a list

Tags: prolog

I have the following knowledge base

```
eliminate(X,[X|T],T).
eliminate(X,[H|T],[H|T2]) :- eliminate(X,T,T2).
```

And I have to make the running process of an example by myself, without the interpreter (like a tree).

For example, if I post the query: `eliminate(3,[1,2,3,4,5],Y)`.

First using the first fact, we unificate X=3, and with the second element, which is a list([1,2,3,4,5]) we try to unify 1 with X, but we can't because X now is 3, so it fails and we try with the second rule.

```
eliminate(3,[1,2,3,4,5],Y).
x = 3, H = 1, T = [2,3,4,5], H = Y , T2 = []
```

This it the part that I am not sure is right. I don't know why `T2` has to be unified with `[]`.

Now with the body clause of the second rule: `eliminate(X,T,T2)`, I have:

```
eliminate(3,[2,3,4,5],[])
x = 3, (here it fails again, so i have to use the second rule)
eliminate(3,[2,3,4,5],[])
x = 3, H = 2, T = [3,4,5], H = Y, T2 =[] ??? is T2 null again???
```

Comment: You need to add the goal `dif(X,H)` in the recursive rule.

Comment: It is called "unify", not "unificate"

Answer (score 0):

T2 doesn't unify with `[]` the first time the second rule is applied. The resolution knows it is a list (because its on the right side of the `[X|Y]` construct), but doesn't know its value yet. To find its value, it will first compute the rule, which will find a value for T2 [recursively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), then unify this value with the `Y` you ran in your query.

In your example, running the query `eliminate(3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], Y).` will do the following:

```
Call eliminate(3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], Y)
2nd rule: X=3, H=1, T=[2,3,4,5], T2=?, Y=[H|?]
Call eliminate(3, [2, 3, 4, 5], ?)
2nd rule: X=3, H=2, T=[3,4,5], T2=??, Y=[H|??]
Call eliminate(3, [3, 4, 5], ??)
1st rule: ??=[4, 5]

Go back one step, using Y=[H|??], H=2 ??=[4,5]: Y = [2|[4,5]] = [2, 4, 5] = ?
Go back another step, using Y=[H|?], H=1, ?=[2, 4, 5]: Y = [1|[2, 4, 5]] = [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

I suggest spending some time reading the recusion chapter of your Prolog learning source. Additionally, to find out how you can see this execution in practice to see what's happening, you can use the `trace.` "command" or other debug equivalent, see [this link](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger) for swi-pl specifics on debugging a program.

Comment: @Merphy one last question, on this step: 2nd rule: X=3, H=1, T=[2,3,4,5], Y shouldn´t be Y=[1,?]???

Comment: @user3105533 yes, but that's because we know `H=1`. I just didn't perform the unification on the `Y` because initially, `Y=[H|?]`, but you're right, in the end it will be `1`.